# Facebook SDK Invite Requests with OmniAuth - Getting the user that sent the request

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, omniauth

I have a facebook app which uses the javascript SDK to allow the user to send invites to their friends to join the app.

Let's say Joe invites Mike.

Mike clicks on the request and is directed to the canvas app, the action which is pointed to in the canvas settings basically does this.

```
redirect_to "/users/auth/facebook?signed_request=#{request.params['signed_request']}&state=canvas"
```

This will sign the user into my application fine. However, I wish to be able to determine that it was Joe who invited Mike so that I can link them up as friends internally in my app.

When decoded, the signed_request does not reveal this, but it does have the request_id. Will I have to do another OpenGraph call with the request_id to find out about Joe and then pass it using the querystring to /users/auth/facebook, or is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

To get info about the request and who it came from you'll have to make a Graph API call to the /[request_id] endpoint. You should get back a JSON response containing the sender. Then you can take it from there.